# Emacs occur mode search for multiple strings

Tags: regex, search, text, emacs

I have a plain text file with multiple patterns. Example:

> DEBUG: i'm a debug line 
>   DEBUG: Another 1 
>   ERROR: this was an error 
>   DEBUG: Another 2 
>   NORMAL: EMACS 
>   DEBUG: Another 3 
>   ERROR: another error

The idea is to use occur-mode to filter the text file with the patterns i want. 
 Example: DEBUG and ERROR. 

As far as i understood occur only works with single string entry or regex. 
How can i use the occur mode to filter more than one string pattern ? If there is another emacs mode to filter strings in text i also accept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass a regexp that matches either of the strings to `occur`.  E.g., type <kbd>M-x</kbd> `occur` <kbd>RET</kbd> `DEBUG\|ERROR`.

Comment: Exacly what i needed i have previously tried that but without the "\". Thank you :)

Comment: lmedinas: Best that you read the Emacs manual on regular expression syntax; you'll probably find there are a lot of other differences to what you're used to, so you'll save yourself some frustration later if you read about them now.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a pattern you often use, here's a bit of elisp (based on legoscia's answer):

```
(defun myoccur (arg)
  (interactive "sList of space-separated args: ")
  (occur (s-replace " " "\\|" arg))
)
```

it replaces the whitespaces with the `OR` regexp construct and calls occur.

ps: `s-replace` is not standard. You need `(require 's)`, the `s.el` library. https://github.com/magnars/s.el

Comment: `s-replace` is not standard.

Comment: True. Looking at its implementation, it is a wrapper around `  (replace-regexp-in-string (regexp-quote to-replace) new-string base-string t t))`